# jQuery Layout pane autoclose

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am using the jQuery Layout plugin to create a page with north and west Pane.
I´d like to show only one pane at a time (If i open the North pane, the west pane should be closed and so on)

I didn't find any functions in the API to do that, aAny idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't find any built-in method or option in the docs; but you can iterate over the panels in the `onopen_start` event and close all the panels.

Code:

```
$('body').layout({
    applyDefaultStyles: true,
    initClosed : true,
    onopen_start: function (pname, pelement, pstate, poptions, lname) {
        var myLayout = $("body").layout();
        $.each(myLayout.panes, function (index, value) {
            if (index !== pname) {
                myLayout.close(index)
            }
        })
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/gH6B7/

Comment: Thank You, thats just what i need !

It´s work great with the "body" but not with div? how should i apply this to the div ?